# Adpating a PowerShell Script (Get-VM) for the use in VMM (Get-SCVirtualMachine)

Tags: powershell, system-center

I'm trying to get a PowerShell Script, for obtaining Informations about the installed VMs in Hyper-V, to work in System Center VMM.
Here is the code which is working in a locally installed Hyper-V installation:

```
$Results = @()
foreach ($VM in (Get-VM))
{
    $Row = "" | Select 'Name','CPUs','Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher','RAM Maximum (in MB)','RAM Minimum (in MB)','Groesse der VHD (in GB)'
    $Row.'Name' = $VM.Name
    $Row.'CPUs' = $VM.ProcessorCount
    $Row.'Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher' = $VM.DynamicMemoryEnabled
    $Row.'RAM Maximum (in MB)' = $VM.MemoryMaximum/1MB
    $Row.'RAM Minimum (in MB)' = $VM.MemoryMinimum/1MB
    $Total=0; ($VM.VMId | Get-VHD | %{$Total += ($_.FileSize/1GB)})
    $Row.'Groesse der VHD (in GB)' = [math]::Round($Total)
    $Results += $Row
}
$Results | Export-Csv c:\vm.csv #-Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv -Path c:\vm.csv | Out-GridView
```

I tried to adapt this code with the needed commands for VMM.
Everything works except for the two lines which are needed for displaying the size.
Here is the full code:

```
$Results = @()
foreach ($VM in (Get-SCVirtualMachine))
{
    $Row = "" | Select 'Name','CPUs','Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher','RAM','Dynamischer RAM Maximum (in MB)','Dynamischer RAM Minimum (in MB)','Groesse der VHD (in GB)'
    $Row.'Name' = $VM.Name
    $Row.'CPUs' = $VM.CPUCount
    $Row.'Dynamischer Arbeitsspeicher' = $VM.DynamicMemoryEnabled
    if($VM.DynamicMemoryEnabled) {
        $Row.'Dynamischer RAM Maximum (in MB)' = $VM.DynamicMemoryMaximumMB
        $Row.'Dynamischer RAM Minimum (in MB)' = $VM.DynamicMemoryMinimumMB
        }
    else{
       $Row.'RAM' = $VM.Memory
        }
    $Total=0; ($VM.VMId | Get-SCVirtualHardDisk | %{$Total += ($_.MaximumSize/1GB)})
    $Row.'Groesse der VHD (in GB)' = [math]::Round($Total)
    $Results += $Row
}
$Results | Export-Csv c:\vm.csv #-Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv -Path c:\vm.csv | Out-GridView
```

Here are the two lines which are causing errors:

```
$Total=0; ($VM.VMId | Get-SCVirtualHardDisk | %{$Total += ($_.MaximumSize/1GB)})
    $Row.'Groesse der VHD (in GB)' = [math]::Round($Total)
```

The error says:

```
Get-SCVirtualHardDisk : VMM is unable to connect to the VMM management server XXX because the specified computer name could 
not be resolved. (Error ID: 1601)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `Get-SCVirtualHardDisk` will accept a VMM virtual machine object as Input, which you are getting from `Get-SCVirtualMachine` so try passng the full object `$VM` instead of only passing the VMId `$VM.VMId` like this: `$VM | Get-SCVirtualHardDisk [...]`

Comment: ` $Row = "" | Select` The correct way would be `$Row = $VM | Select-Object @{Name = "Dynamischer RAM"; Expression = {$_.DynamicMemoryEnabled}}` and so on